# Can JNBridge be used under linux?

Tags: c#, java, mono, java-interop

I have to consume some C# dll's under a linux host through java.  Rewriting the code is currently not an option, and we can't expose the dll as a service because this linux server will exist in isolation.

Is it possible to generate my "java to .net" proxy JARS on a windows host with JNBridge, and then consume them under my linux box (presumably with mono).

This seems feasible in theory, but seeing as I have no experience with JNBridge or even mono I don't know if this is even possible, or what the degree of difficulty would be.  Or, is there is a better route to go to solve my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: JNBridgePro now supports Mono and can be run under Linux.  Please see the JNBridge website for more information.**

Shredder -- For some reason I can't do this as a comment on your comment, so I have to provide a reply.

JNBridgePro does not support Mono directly.  jdigital's suggestion, to run the .NET inside a Windows VM, is the one we would recommend, although we would recommend that you use JNBridgePro to bridge between the Java code and the .NET code running in the VM.  In this case, you would use the JNBridgePro tcp/binary channel to do the bridging.

You could use a Web service if it would work for you, but since you were considering JNBridgePro, I had figured that Web services weren't appropriate for your project.  In general, JNBridgePro provides a number of capabilities not offered by Web services, including faster performance, cross-platform access to a finer-grained object-oriented API, and use of cross-platform pass-by-value and remote references.

Wayne Citrin -- JNBridge

Comment: Much thanks for the response.  I will experiment with JNBridgePro and calling my .NET classes that reside in a VM.

Answer (score 1):

The [JNBridge web site says that Windows is required](http://www.jnbridge.com/jnbp-sysreq.htm).  How about using a Windows VM for the .NET code (it shouldn't  matter if your Linux server is in isolation)?

Comment: Hmm never thought about that.  So expose the c# libraries via webservices in the VM?